# E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

While installing Paper-theme on my Elementary 0.3.2 Freya it got frozen and restarted, and since then I can't install nor delete anything. 
"E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." - this is what I get all the time.
I tried couple links but the problem remains.

Comment: So did you run 'sudo dkpg --configure -a' ?

Comment: I did. Whenever I do that laptop freezes permanently, so have to restart it. I tried to delete /var/lib/dpkg/updates won't happen either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some blind actions I opened Nautilus as root and found `/var/lib/dpkg/update/` and deleted all the files in it. Now everything is working as it used to.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! /$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/update/** # begone