# DKPG problems on Ubuntu 18.04 with Wireguard

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, wireguard

I ran into a brick wall installing wireguard on my System running Ubuntu 18.04, ever since then i can't seem to be able to install apps. I always get a prompt >E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

i have tried running 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' but at the end it just gets stuck. i have embedded a screenshot showing the error  [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvTfk.png)

Comment: Try to fully uninstall wireguard: "sudo apt-get --purge remove wireguard"
if the program was installed..

Comment: i have tried the command "sudo apt-get --purge remove wireguard" but i am still getting the **'sudo dpkg --configure -a'** error

Comment: ok, unfortunately it is late for me here, I will try and solve this in the morning.

Comment: Welcome martinkem to askubuntu! Don't post images if they only contain terminal output.

Comment: @abu_bua ok, I'd take it for next time

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Wireguard on my HP Envy. I cleared /var/lib/dpkg/updates. None of the other files/directories in dpkg held anything pertinent.

Source: [DPKG Problem - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859435/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-you-must-manually-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a-to-cor?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.